# Enforce 2-digit citation numbers?

Tags: bibtex, numbering, citing, multibib

I need citation numbers to be at least two digits. So, any number less than 10 needs to be prefixed with a zero: [01], [02] ... [10]

Is it possible to that in bibtex, or any other citation package?

I am using standard IEEE paper style and the multibib package, but I would appreciate an answer in any package or style.

```
    \documentclass[10pt,journal,cspaper,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{multibbl}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to do it with standard BibTeX, though you'll have to supply your own references for the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svbibcite\bibcite
\def\bibcite#1#2{\svbibcite{#1}{\ifnum#2<10\relax0#2\else#2\fi}}
\makeatletter
\let\svbiblabel\@biblabel
\def\@biblabel#1{\ifnum#1<10\svbiblabel{0#1}\else\svbiblabel{#1}\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
cite \cite{segl83, alli63, plen66, blis81, dipe68, dipe65, grin05a,
grin05b, grin09a, huff85}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{segletes}
\end{document}
```

[image]